# The method trimToSize() is undefined for the type List<Integer>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm running the following code, but getting error `The method trimToSize() is undefined for the type List<Integer>`

```
public class ListPerformance {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> linked  = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        //Initialize array with random elements in the first 50 positions, do other operations
        addElement(array,"beginning"); 
        //Resize to 100

        for(int a=100;a<array.size();a++) {
            array.remove(a);
        }
        linked.trimToSize();
    }
    ...
```

I thought I did everything correctly as shown at [this tutorial on ArrayList.trimToSize()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_trimtosize.htm). Why can't I use `.trimToSize()` here?

EDIT2: So thanks to the posters/commenters, I now know that my mistake was creating with element of List instead of ArrayList. But what about custom methods? Should I take those as arraylist/linked list or regular ol' List? What is considered "good-practice"? Or does that also depend on whether or not I need to use ArrayList-specific methods?

Thanks again!

Comment: For future reference, the hint you need is right there in the error message: it's undefined **for the type `List<Integer>`**.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks all three of you, speedy replies too, to boot!

Unfortunately I can't give anyone a best answer because I thought all three were equally helpful. :(

Answer (score 4):

`trimToSize()` is a method of the `ArrayList` class, not the `List` interface. Since you're storing your variables as `List<Integer>`, you can only use methods that are part of the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface.

Change your variable declarations to:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
LinkedList<Integer> linked  = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

And you should be fine in your `main`, so long as you only try and trim `array`. You can't trim `linked` at all, because it's nonsensical to trim a `LinkedList`; they do not allocate additional buffer space past their capacity as appending to a `LinkedList` is always *O(1)*, where as appending to a full `ArrayList` is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

trimToSize() is a method of ArrayList but not of List. Not all Lists can be trimmed (e.g.: LinkedList)

```
List<Integer> linked  = new LinkedList<Integer>();
linked.trimToSize();
```

You're calling it on the LinkedList. If you want to call it on the ArrayList use

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

instead of the first line. (tell your compiler it's not any List, but an ArrayList)